# Will I be able to turn off unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)

I heard that unity launcher will have to be on the left side, but i like the OSX look with awn on the bottom. Using both awn and launcher would look ugly. Will I be able to completely turn off(not hide) the launcher?

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to select the normal GNOME desktop at login, much like you now can select different installed Desktop Environments (like KDE, XFCE, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You can use classic Gnome Desktop with your favourite Dock.