# Can I get rid of the launcher in Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)

Just wondering if I can get rid of the launcher in the Unity desktop and replace it by something else?

Comment: The question this is a duplicate of has since been made a duplicate of [this other question, so this is the one to look at](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher).