# How to get rid of the launcher in Unity?

Tags: unity, dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)
>   [Can I get rid of the launcher in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42316/can-i-get-rid-of-the-launcher-in-unity)

I have this dock installed (on the right in my screenshot) and i'd like it to completely replace the launcher.

Right clicking on the bar did nothing, nor did [Alt]+[Super]+[Right click]

I'm also pretty much a newb in Ubuntu, so please take that into account when answering :)

Thx, you guys rule!

[image: Desktop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a new session that uses the dock alone. I believe then what you need is `cairo-dock`. It will install a new session that you can select from your login screen, which allows you to use a dock-only session (so the Unity launcher and panel will not show up there).

When you login to the computer, there will be a button with the Ubuntu logo next to your name (don't enter your password yet).

Click this button and you will get a list of "sessions" that you can log in to. Choose Cairo-dock, and then enter your password and hit enter. You will not login to a Cairo-Dock session from now on.

Comment: cairo-dock installed. When i login, no sign of anything you mentioned appears. I don't understand anything else from what you said, could you please elaborate a little? thx

Comment: @Roland - please add your answer to the linked Q&A and delete this one.  We'll get the correct search redirect with this search term.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom this one is not really the same as those, I suggest he open a new question that would specify what he wants more appropriately.