# How do I remove the launcher?

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)

What I want, is the top bar from Unity and nothing else. Everything I've tried so far has failed. I've installed compiz, but there doesn't seem to be any options to permanently hide the launcher (the bar on the left) from the screen entirely. Is there a way to remove it?