# Unity Launcher ignores Compiz Settings

Tags: 11.04, compiz, launcher

I've followed the steps in a number of other posts on askubuntu. Installed compiz, set the launcher to autohide and reveal mode to none. Yet, the launcher somehow maintains it's default setting to dodge windows and reacts to left reveal.

I've tried updating in three manners:

1. With compiz settings manager
2. Manually with gconf-editor
3. Manually with dconf write.

None of these seem to work.

Here's a frustrating screen shot with the setting showing up correct in compiz setting manager, but the launcher still learing at me.

[image]

RELATED: [Previous Question (RESOLVED)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65963/how-do-i-remove-the-launcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell by your [screenshot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39444/whats-the-visual-difference-between-unity-3d-and-unity-2d) that you are using [Unity 2D](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D). All the methods you were using are for Unity.

- [How to configure Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d).