# Launcher flyout, how do I change it?

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity's launcher auto-hide behavior?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior)

The one thing that's starting to drive me mad with ubuntu is the launcher on the left side of the screen, I think it looks just pain and ulgy and anytime I want to use a button or back on my browser the launcher flyout and gets in the way. I can't find anyway to customise it or control it's actions. As much as I love using Ubuntu unless I can change the way it works, I'll be looking for an alternative distro it's gotten so bad.

Please can anyone give me some advice on how to make my experience more enjoyable.

Comment: See these two answers. Hope it helps!

http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher

http://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher

Comment: Window managers != distribution. Hard to tell from your post if you would find an alternate window manager or an alternate distribution more suited to your needs. I would try x/k/lubuntu first. Moving to an alternate distribution is unlikely to help as gnome 2 is not longer maintained and you will then need to be willing to learn yum, pacman, emerge ...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like Unity, then there's no need to switch distro, just switch desktop!

To install plain gnome-shell by clicking [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell), then log out (maybe restart?), use the gear icon to choose a new session type, log in, and see if you like that.

There's also [KDE](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kubuntu-desktop), [LXDE](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lubuntu-desktop), and [XFCE](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xubuntu-desktop) to choose from, of course.