# how to get the unity bar only hide when a window is maximize

Tags: unity, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make the launcher hide when dodge windows in 12.04 like in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109249/how-to-make-the-launcher-hide-when-dodge-windows-in-12-04-like-in-11-10)

How do I do this? in ubuntu 12.04 it never go away or when a window wasn't  maximize it go way anyways. I don't like that. How can i make it like it was in ubuntu 11.10, 11.04, 10.10 netbook editon the unity bar only goway when a window is maximize on that desktop.

Comment: does this question and answer help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior/106673#106673   or are you referring to the dodge window capability in 11.10?