# How can I make the unity launcher pop out in 12.04 as it did in 11.10?

Tags: 12.04, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109249/how-do-i-configure-the-launcher-to-dodge-windows)

Either it's there all the time or it's completely gone forever! Annoying. I prefer the way it handled in 11.10, where you had the program open in full screen in cursing over to the left side made the unity launcher pop out.