# Unity Panel Oneiric behavior on Precise

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109249/how-do-i-configure-the-launcher-to-dodge-windows)

One of the good thing of Ubuntu 11.10 was to see the launcher except when a window was in fullscreen.

With Precise, the new behavior is always visible or always hidden.

How to make it act as before ?