# How to make the Unity launcher evade active windows in 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109249/how-do-i-configure-the-launcher-to-dodge-windows)

In 11.x, my Unity launcher remained visible all the time, except when the active window went over it.

I cannot find the feature in 12.04 anymore. There is only an autohide (the launcher *always* hides) and a no-hide (a.k.a. panel mode) option.

**How can I get the feature back in 12.04, in Unity 3D and in Unity 2D?**

--

Thanks in advance.