# How to get the launcher in 12.04 to "dodge windows" like it does in 11.10?

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109249/how-do-i-configure-the-launcher-to-dodge-windows)

I want the 12.04 launcher to act like it did in 11.10, Where it would only hide if it was being dodge by a window not remain hidden until you touch the left side of screen with your mouse, like it does in 12.04.

Is there anyone way to do that?