# Launcher feature  "dodge windows" is no longer available in 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109249/how-do-i-configure-the-launcher-to-dodge-windows)

Previously, the launcher will be autohide when we maximize the window of any applications and will remain visible when there is no active application opened. In 12.04 this feature is no longer there and the only choice is to autohide or always show the launcher as in Windows.

Is there any way I can get it back to previous state like describe above?

Comment: Please see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/130564/get-12-04-panel-acting-like-11-10