# Minimize on click / dodge windows in Unity under 12.10

Tags: unity, launcher, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109249/how-do-i-configure-the-launcher-to-dodge-windows)

I would like to have minimize on click / dodge windows in Unity under 12.10: Minimized windows to restore, or windows to minimize if they aren't, by clicking the launcher. There was a patch available for 12.04 but it doesn't carry over to 12.10 so now I'm back to the old behaviour: Windows restored if minimized but nothing happening for windows open on the desktop when clicking the launcher.

Does anyone know how I can get this functionality in 12.10.

Comment: this behaviour is missing by canonical design.

However, Webupd8 has a patch in its ppa for 12.04, not for 12.10, but since many users want this feature you should observe the webupd8 Blog for a 12.10 release for this patch (http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-get-dodge-windows-and-minimize.html)

Comment: It is not what you asked but CTRL + META + D minimises all windows.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that would be the answer. Oh well, personally I fail to see the rationale behind not having windows dodge with the launcher especially since clicking on the launcher for an open window does nothing. I'll keep an eye out for a 12.10 update in webupd8.org hoping Canonical change their design in this regard in the future or at least build it in as an option in Unity.