# How To Get Dodge Windows And Minimize On Click For Unity In Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity

I would like to have this on ubuntu 13.10

the solutions in this post http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-get-dodge-windows-and-minimize.html doesnt'work actually. I install ccsm and the option is not present

Comment: Your question is very vague, and makes it difficult to help you.  which solution? -what about it doesn't work?

Comment: There has been no workaround for the Minimize on click for anything later than 12.04, but you can get the dodge windows back; see this question http://askubuntu.com/a/387274/65969  the dodge windows is functional but not quite the same as the original. be sure to read the article that is linked in the answer..

Comment: @virtualxtc none of it will work, the page he is linking to is for a 12.04 ppa with a patched Unity that is at least 3 updates out of date, it doesn't even work on 12.04 anymore and never worked on 13.04 up

Comment: Oh strange, I just saw that the ppa had rolled some .deb files for saucy and assumed it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit this command...

- but the first you have to have [ccsm](http://www.compiz.org/)..

> ```
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```

enjoy