# How can I remove the unity launcher, but keep the dash home menu?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, dockbarx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)

Is it possible to remove the Unity launcher? I've replaced it with a different launcher (dockbarX) however I would like to keep the Dash Home feature. I don't need a button if I can control it with the super key.

So far my workaround was to comment out everything in /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher/Launcher.qml, however windows will no longer go fullscreen as the space that was previously used by the Unity Launcher has remained.