# Is it possible to remove the launcher entirely, but keep the dash functionality, of Unity in 12.10?

Tags: unity, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)

I have read on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112359/how-can-i-remove-the-unity-launcher-but-keep-the-dash-home-menu) post that it is possible to completely remove the launcher from Unity while retaining other features. How can this be done in 12.10? The problem is in the fact that 12.10 no longer has a Unity 2D session.

Comment: If you're using Unity 3D the only way is to compile it without the launcher:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/719870/compile-unity-without-launcher