# Launcher and top panel removing

Tags: launcher, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)

I kindly ask to help about removing Launcer, but not in way to have classic panel. I want to remove launcher and top panel and put shortcut at the desktop. Please help.