# I want to remove side bar ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I want to get rid of the sidebar in Ubuntu. What should I do? Version 14.04 is available. It is not auto-hide.

I have tried all of the following commands but it does not work. The terminal is touch-based and when I put 4 fingers on it, I want to make the main menus of Ubuntu come out.

following commands :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt 

sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

Answer (score 2):

Install [unity-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/), click on Launcher and enable auto-hide feature. You will not uninstall it, but at least it will not disturb you.

Look at [How do I remove the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher)